# Verify events sent to Google Tag Manager using the Swift iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have an iOS app in which I've integrated the Firebase SDK and I can see some basic events firing on the Firebase console as expected.

As a next step, I wanted to integrated Google Tag Manager and I followed this [step by step guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5) to integrate Google Tag Manager into an iOS project.

Everything seems to be set up correctly and when I try to preview if the work is done correctly as per [these steps](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5#4_preview_debug_and_publish_your_container) - nothing seems to happen. The documentation also doesn't really mention what should happen in preview mode but all I can see are the events on the Firebase console but I have no way to verify if the Google Tag manager set up has been done correctly.

Please could someone suggest how to verify if Google Tag manager has been integrated correctly for a native iOS app ?